# How to set shutdown script via powershell

Tags: powershell

It is possible to add shutdown script via powershell in
[image]

Is there any cmdlet for that?

Comment: Not directly, you can try using `secedit.exe` for that, though.

Comment: There are Group Policy Cmdlets available but I don't know whether they supports adding a startup script: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx

Comment: I want to add powershell startup script to windows startup event via powershell cmdlet.

Comment: You can use [registry based policy](http://serverfault.com/questions/377387/how-to-add-a-shutdown-script-not-by-using-gpedit-msc-or-active-directory), with all the caveats and implications that implies.